# How to use phpunit to check if a Testloader works?

Tags: testing, phpunit, phar

I downloaded PHPUnit using `wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar` and then tried to run `php phpunit.phar --loader PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader`.

But I got

> Could not use "PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader" as loader..

Can anyone tell me if there is anything wrong with the command I am using?

Answer (score 2):

In the phpunit.xml file, instead of
testSuiteLoaderClass="PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader"
use
testSuiteLoaderFile="/path/to/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php"

Example:
testSuiteLoaderFile="phpunit/src/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php"